# Discord bot (either Python or Javascript) that can store information

Tags: javascript, python, discord

So I was thinking of making a Discord bot for a Dungeons and Dragons server for me and my friends when I realized that (gasp) I don't know how to create variables or store information when it comes to Discord bots.

(Yes, I do know how to make variables in regular Python, if that helps. I also know how to set up a bot and add it to Discord, I just need to get the hard coding down)

So therefore, I hath decided to ask ye Stack Overflow gods, dispensers of coding wisdom and masters of carpal tunnel, to assist me with... figuring out how to make a bot that can store information and such. Fair warning, this will probably be the first of many questions.

TL;DR: Could someone please help me make a bot that can store information about a fictional character(s) (i.e. name, age, etc.)?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Overall, you seem to be looking for individual hand-holding to build a project that is notably beyond your current programming skills.  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `shelve` for python. You interact with it like it's a python dictionary/map, but it saves to a file.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use this

```
  if msg.startswith("g?list"):
    fb = []
    if "fb" in db.keys():
      fb = db["fb"]
    await message.channel.send(fb)

  await client.process_commands(message)
```

just make sure to change the command prefix to whatever your bots command prefix is.